# Reroute replies from one group to another

Tags: google-groups

I am using Google Groups. I have a group with email id: `example@support.com`, which I am using to send out emails to clients. I want all the replies to this mail id to be redirected to other groups based on the mail I send. Is this possible?

Comment: This question doesn't look like a practical, detailed question. Please check out the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a [content compliance rule](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1346934) to send Inbound emails a different location based on the information they contain.